# Filling a select box of a form using the text inside the <option> tags with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html-select, casperjs

I would like to fill the "Acheter un billet" form of this site : http://www.leguichet.fr/

This is what I've done so far :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.leguichet.fr/', function() {
  this.fill('form#search_tickets', {'departure':'1', 'arrival':'2'}, false);
  this.click('input[value="Rechercher"]');
  this.wait(1000, function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
  });
});

casper.run(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```

The documentation says that fill() uses the value attribute to match against but I would like to use the text inside the option tags. For instance they have :

```
<option value="Montpellier">Montpellier</option>
<option value="Montpellier">Béziers</option>
```

Thus if I want to select Béziers I have to write 'departure':'Montpellier'.
Is there a way to use the text inside the option tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to retrieve the element value of the option that you want to select and use that value later. It may be the case that during the subsequent selection another option is selected, but the value will be the same, so it should *not* make a difference:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.start('http://www.leguichet.fr/', function() {

  var textToSelect = "Béziers";
  var value = this.getElementAttribute(x("//form[@id='search_tickets']//select[@name='departure']/option[contains(text(), '" + text + "')]"), 'value');

  this.fill('form#search_tickets', {'departure': value, 'arrival':'2'}, false);

  this.click('input[value="Rechercher"]');
  this.wait(1000, function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl())
  });
});
```

You can easily select DOM nodes with XPath by testing their text content with the `text()` function. Do the same thing for `arrival`.

Comment: Thanks for answering Artjom B.
I tried it but it didnt work, even after changing textToSelect by text.
If i add this.echo(value) before this.fill it says that value is null.

Comment: ok i found out ... missing bracket : [contains(text(), '" + text + "')]